# Using Membership in ASP.Net MVC throws exception

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am trying to use the membership for my MVC project. I have added references of

WebMatrix.Data 2.0.0.0

WebMatrix.WebData 2.0.0.0

When I try to run my project it throws an exception

"Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.OnConnectionOpened(System.Object, WebMatrix.Data.ConnectionEventArgs)' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.HttpContextExtensions.RegisterForDispose(System.Web.HttpContextBase, System.IDisposable)' failed."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question lacks any sort of real data with which other users can attempt to assist you. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question, providing more information.

Answer (score 2):

The IIS process does not have rights to access your database. 
As a fix, make sure that the application pool identity user has access to the folder and files of your database.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I prove access to the database?

Comment: Please google: "setting access rights in windows explorer"

Answer (score 1):

same case with me

"Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.OnConnectionOpened(System.Object, WebMatrix.Data.ConnectionEventArgs)' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.HttpContextExtensions.RegisterForDispose(System.Web.HttpContextBase, System.IDisposable)' failed."